# How to Design HBase Schema

Tags: schema, hadoop, hbase

We have currently one running project which uses RDBMS database( with lots of tables and stored procedures for manipulating data). The current flow is like : the data access layer will call stored procedures, which will insert/delete/update or fetch data from RDBMS(please note that these stored procedures are not doing any bulk proccesses.). The current data structure contains lots of primary key, foreign key relation ship and have lots of updates to existing database tables.a I just want to know whether we can use HBase for our purpose? then how can we use Hadoop with HBase replacing RDBMS?

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/1228) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6329366/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask yourself, what is the RDBMS not doing for you, and what is it that you hope to achieve by moving to Hadoop/HBase?

This article may help. There are a lot more.
http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/madgreek/nosql-vs-rdbms-apples-and-oranges-37713

If the purpose is trying new technology, I suggest trying their tutorial/getting started.

If it's a clear problem you're trying to solve, then you may want to articulate the problem.

Good Luck!

Comment: @charbelcurrent system have performance problems is the first point.Also we want to convert current system into distributed KVS for high available,fault tolerant and performance improvement system(also we are evaluating KVS parameters interim). so iam confused in migrating current relationship data/schema( with complex data structure) into non-structured or semi-structured data. When using hbase (as its store key value store), we are facing problem of lack of join tables ( as in RBDMS) to fetch data. Is there any way to search data in column family in an effective manner using HBase?

Comment: I think what @Charbel is saying is that you have to completely redesign your schema and how you use the system.  As you point out, there is no concept of a join.  That means that you should denormalize your design and rethink how you integrate your app and your data store

Comment: @Carbel,Thanks for the reply. Actually consider one simple usecase. suppose i have two relationship tables employee and dept in RDBMS. In RDBMS, I can retrieve data by joining these tables using sql query as they have primary- foreign key relation. But how can i design the same tables in hbase? or how can i keep the same relation using hbase? i need data from both these tables ( after joining) .. how can I possible it in Hbase?

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to suggest replacing your current rdbms simply because of the large developer effort that you've already spent. Consider that your organization probably has no employees with the needed experience for hbase. Moving to hbase with the attendant data conversion and application rewriting will be very expensive and risky.